# Jolt spec for conditional presence of field

Tags: json, jolt

I have a scenario where I have two very similar inputs formats, but I need one Jolt spec to process both formats consistently.

This is **input style 1**:

```
{
    "creationTime": 1503999158000,
    "device": {
        "ip": "155.157.36.226",
        "hostname": "server-123.example.int"
    }
}
```

and this is **input style 2**:

```
{
    "creationTime": 1503999158000,
    "device": {
        "ip6": "2001::face",
        "hostname": "server-123.example.int"
    }
}
```

The only difference is that **style 1** uses `device.ip`, and **style 2** uses `device.ip6`.  There will always be one or neither of those fields, but never both.

I want to simply extract the following:

```
{
    "created_ts": 1503999158000,
    "src_ip_addr": "....."
}
```

I need `src_ip_addr` to be set to whichever field was present out of `ip` and `ip6`.  If neither field was present in the source data, the value should default to `null`.

Is this possible with a single Jolt spec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single spec with two operations.

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "creationTime": "created_ts",
      "device": {
        // map ip or ip6 to src_ip_addr
        "ip|ip6": "src_ip_addr"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      // if src_ip_addr does not exist, then apply a default of null
      "src_ip_addr": null
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Milo. Is there any difference between using my version to yours?

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the following and it worked for my requirements:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "creationTime": "created_ts",
      "device": {
        // map both to src_ip_addr, whichever one is present will be used
        "ip": "src_ip_addr",
        "ip6": "src_ip_addr"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "src_ip_addr": null
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: While this works, I'll accept Milo S's answer seeing as that'd be the official method.